# using OR within a sumproduct

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a table:

```
a        1

b        2

c        3
```

and I want to use a `SUMPRODUCT` that will give me the total if the cell is `a` or `b`.

I have a cell that shows:

```
a/b
```

and I want to use either `SUMIF` or `SUMPRODUCT` to give me the total if it is `a` or `b`.

I wrote this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A4=LEFT(A7,1)))
```

Do you think there is a way to use an OR within the `SUMPRODUCT` so that it can check for `b` within the table and give the total of that?

Comment: This is do-able but in order to answer, would you mind positing the table definition more clearly as I don't follow?

Comment: Still don't get it. How about you post the rectangle bounded by A1 to B7?

Comment: You can do two in one with this version `=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,{"a","b"},B:B))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a SUMPRODUCT formula `OR` is `+`. `AND` is `*`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A4=LEFT(A7,1))+(A2:A4=LEFT(B7,1))
```

Comment: This one gave me a count. Is there a way to use sumproduct for the sum in column b?

Comment: SUMIF would be better for a sum as per other suggestions here, but you can simply add the sum range like this `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=LEFT(A7,1))+(A2:A4=LEFT(B7,1)),B2:B4)` - note that `--` isn't required